# Как пропускать не unique_index и записывать в MySQL только unique_index

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

при записи в таблицу нужна уникальность по полям email и phone 
в mysql выполнил:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`email`, `phone`);
```

в модели распаковываю csv файл и пытаюсь записать таким методом:

```
public function writeCSVFile($filename)
{
    $handle = fopen($this->getFolder().$filename, 'r');

    while (($item = fgetcsv($handle,0, ";"))){
        try {
            $db_contact = new DbContact();
            $db_contact->base_id    = $this->id;
            $db_contact->email      = (isset($item[0])) ? $item[0] : null;
            $db_contact->phone      = (isset($item[1])) ? $item[1] : null;
            $db_contact->master_id  = (isset($item[2])) ? $item[2] : null;
            $db_contact->name       = (isset($item[3])) ? $item[3] : null;
            $db_contact->company    = (isset($item[4])) ? $item[4] : null;
            $db_contact->post       = (isset($item[5])) ? $item[5] : null;
            $db_contact->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            continue;
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);

    self::deleteCSVFiles('uploads/');
}
```

но конечно же возникает ошибка при добавление не уникальных записей по полям unique_index:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry for key 'unique_index'
```

как сделать так, что бы не unique_index пропускать, а unique_index записывать?

Comment: поставьте на уровне модели валидацию этих полей

Comment: @madfan41k можно по подробнее, что именно написать в rules? Спасибо.

Comment: @madfan41k, спасибо, добавил [['email', 'phone'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'phone']] и все ок

Comment: был занят, рад что Вы разобрались

Comment: batchInsert более выгодно использовать в данном случае. При этом при подготовке массива, можно легко исключить дубли.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, расскажите пожалуйста подробнее как можно исключить дубли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы попробовал вот такой вариант. Написал проверку только для email.

```
// получим данные из БД и добавим их в контрольный массив
$uniqueEmail = []; // сюда положить массив мыл

// in_array() работает медленнее, поэтому значения массива делаем ключами
// и ищем по наличию ключа c помощью isset()
$uniqueEmail = array_flip($uniqueEmail);

$handle = fopen($this->getFolder().$filename, 'r');
// готовим массив для записи в БД
$batch = [];
while ($item = fgetcsv($handle,0, ";")){
    $row = [];
    $email = $item[0] ?? '';

    // если есть мыло и оно уже в БД, либо готово к записи в БД
    if ($email && isset($uniqueEmail[$email])) {
        continue;
    }

    // если мыла нет, добавляем его в контрольный массив как ключ с любым значением
    // и добавляем к записи в БД
    $uniqueEmail[$email] = true;

    $row[] = $email;
    // другие поля

    $batch[] = $row;
}

// пишем в БД с помощью batchInsert
$fields = ['email']; // очередность полей должна соответствовать очередности в $row
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
    ->batchInsert(User::tableName(), $fields, $batch)
    ->execute();
```

Такой вариант записи в БД не предусматривает валидацию данных. Если валидация необходима, стоит добавить динамическую модель для валидации.

Comment: а если в таблице пусто, то как быть тогда?

Comment: Ничего страшного. Тогда контрольный массив будет пустой и будет наполняться в цикле при подготовке массива.

Answer (score 0):

спасибо madfan41k, добавил в rules:

```
[['email', 'phone'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['email', 'phone']],
```

и все ок.